# Mongodb is it possible to specify "skip" as the range of index?

Tags: mongodb, pagination

In Mongodb for pagination is it possible to specify skip as the range of index, that is suppose I am on page 6, and I want to skip docs from `(1-59)` and return docs at `(0 & 60-70)` is it possible to do in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get the data specifying multiple ranges using Aggregation Framework. Every pagination needs to start with [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) to get the data in deterministic order. Then you can use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html) to apply multiple [$skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/index.html) and [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/index.html) on sorted data set based on your range. In the next stages you need to [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/index.html) from multiple ranges and then use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) with [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to get original documents shape, try in Mongo shell:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    db.col.save({ _id: i })
} 


db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $sort: { _id: 1 }
    },
    {
        $facet: {
            range1: [ { $limit: 1 } ],
            range2: [ { $skip: 60 }, { $limit: 11 } ]
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            docs: { $concatArrays: [ "$range1", "$range2" ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$docs"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$docs"
        }
    }
])
```

outputs:

```
{ "_id" : 0 }
{ "_id" : 60 }
{ "_id" : 61 }
{ "_id" : 62 }
{ "_id" : 63 }
{ "_id" : 64 }
{ "_id" : 65 }
{ "_id" : 66 }
{ "_id" : 67 }
{ "_id" : 68 }
{ "_id" : 69 }
{ "_id" : 70 }
```